# what are the differences between assignment symbols =, := and <- if any?

Tags: algorithm, operators, computer-science, pseudocode

While going through Pseudocodes and codes of algorithms, I frequently encounter these assignment operators. What are the differences between them. Is there any rule for which assignment operator to choose?

Comment: If it's pseudocode then any "rules" are arbitrarily defined by whoever writes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference. Problem with `=` is that it confuses many people as it is more commonly used by scientists as the equals to operator. `:=` was used by Pascal programming language to express the assignment, and makes the difference with `=` to test equality. Algorithmic pseudo-language frequently use `<-` for assignment, suggesting that the value of the right part is *pushed* onto the variable on the left.

Choose the one that people around you usually use. Conventions are conventions : arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

No rules. People with [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) background like `=`, people with [ALGOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL) and [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29) background like `:=` more, and notation like `<-` might come from [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29).